# Trying to understand go func with WaitGroup

Tags: go

I have the following code https://play.golang.org/p/9jPlypO4d-

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                    if <-c == -1 {
                            fmt.Print(":")
                            return
                    }

                    fmt.Print(".")
                    time.Sleep(time.Second)
            }

    }()

    c <- 0
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    c <- -1
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I wonder why there is only one `.` printed?  Shouldn't it be like 4 or 5?

Comment: How many times do you think you are sending to the channel?

Comment: @saarrrr mentioned you're sending value only once to channel. Try changing this line `c <- 0` into  `for i:=0; i<5; i++ { c <- i }`

Answer (score 3):

`if <-c == -1` will block until there is something in the channel.  So, the first value is 0, it gets it, prints out a `.`, sleeps one second (while outside the goroutine it is sleeping 5 seconds), then it blocks until it gets the next value.  And then it returns.

The only way to read a channel without blocking (that I know of) is to use a select statement with a default case.

```
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case x, ok := <-c:
            if ok && x == -1 {
                fmt.Print(":")
                return
            }
        default:
            fmt.Print(".")
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

}()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nOG_hfih4D

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose I misunderstood the channel.  How do I make the go func keep printing '.' until a quit signal is received?

Comment: The only way to read a channel without blocking (that I know of) is to use a `select` statement with a default case. https://play.golang.org/p/nOG_hfih4D

Comment: another way, though slightly hacky is to use `reflect.ValueOf(c).TryRecv()` where `c` is a channel